# adobe brackets-shell : cef extract failed

Tags: adobe-brackets, brackets-shell

I followed all the step is mention in given below url to build my project( I am using win7 OS).

https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-brackets-shell.

actullly i want to create brackets installer (installed wix 3.7).
but i am getting cef-extract failed error.

even though i also used grunt cef-extract --force.

after that its throunging new error.

create -project failed after that i am not able to process further.

can some one help me.

thanks in advanced.

Regards
ashish .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include the exact console output you're seeing, it would be much easier to help you. But based on snags other people have encountered recently, you can try these things:

- Make sure your PATH includes Python 2.7 ([otherwise "create-project" will fail](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/4532)).
- Delete all these folders to be sure you're starting from a clean slate: `deps`, `Debug`, `include`, `libcef_dll`, `Release`, `Resources`.
- Just run the high-level tasks `grunt setup` and `grunt build`, following the [Building brackets-shell](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-brackets-shell) instructions. (There's a [known bug](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/4493) where `grunt cef-extract` fails when run standalone).